# Java incompatible types error

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Numbers {

    // --------------------------------------------
    // Reads in an array of integers, sorts them,
    // then prints them in sorted order.
    // --------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                int[] intList;
        int size;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nHow many integers do you want to sort? ");
        size = scan.nextInt();
        intList = new int[size];

        System.out.println("\nEnter the numbers...");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            intList[i] = scan.nextInt();
        Sorting.selectionSort(intList);


        System.out.println("\nYour numbers in sorted order...");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            System.out.print(intList[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

//CODE OF FIRST .

```
public class Sorting {

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sorts the specified array of objects using the selection
    // sort algorithm.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
public static void selectionSort(Comparable[] list) {

    int min;
    Comparable temp;
    for (int index = 0; index < list.length - 1; index++) {
        min = index;
    for (int scan = index + 1; scan < list.length; scan++)
        if (list[scan].compareTo(list[min]) < 0)

                    min = scan;
            // Swap the values
            temp = list[min];
            list[min] = list[index];
            list[index] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this code will not work. It might be simple, but I'm not sure.
Here is the running of the program.

run:

How many integers do you want to sort? 1

Enter the numbers...
12

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Sorting.selectionSort
    at Numbers.main(Numbers.java:29)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Its giving me the error on the intList on the top code.

Comment: Just use a debugger.

Comment: @Garret, edit your post with the exact error message.

Comment: What do you mean by *this code will not work*: it doesn't compile, it doesn't run, runs but a `RuntimeException` raises, runs but gives unexpected output...?

Comment: do you know what line your error is on?

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to convert an `int[]` to a `Comparable[]`.  Normally, widening conversions are allowed for object reference types, but `int[]` is an array of a primitive type, so the conversion fails and a compiler error is generated.

Try using an `int[]` as the parameter of `selectionSort`.  Or you can use an `Integer[]` for the type of `intList`.

Comment: Welcome to the joys of Java's broken type-variance.

Comment: @KenoguLabz that's not Java's broker type variance. Primitive and reference types are not the same.

Comment: True.  That's its own separate issue.  There is the problem, though, of writing to a covariant array.  The saving grace is that the written values are always pulled from the array in the first place.

Comment: `Integer[] intList;` and `intList = new Integer[size];`, or `public static void selectionSort(int[] list) {`.

Comment: Now I have to copy that code and make it read in strings instead of Integers. Do you know how i could do that? I keep getting this error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: hw05.Sorting.selectionSort
 at hw05.Strings.main(Strings.java:32)
Java Result: 1

Comment: That just means that the `java` executable couldn't compile a source file that changed.  Compile that file normally with `javac` and you'll get a proper compiler error.